# Can't read and can't enter the data in online form in selenium and Java program runs then getting below error

Tags: java, excel, apache, google-chrome, selenium

```
package paymenttransfer;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    public class PaymentTransfer {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",           "C:\\Users\\u524915\\workspace\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        FileInputStream fis=new   `  FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\U524915\\workspace\\Data.xlsx");
        Workbook wb= WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        //Sheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus",true);
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        //Going to the web address
        driver.get("https://pspsit.wellsfargo.com/?coid=wfps01&id=mohamm01");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //Clicking the Online wire from the left hand pane
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'Online   Wires')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_17")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Clicking on the new payment tab
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'New Payment')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Clicking the currency drop down
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_9A")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Clicking the US Dollar
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_PickListMenu_0_body_cell0_0")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Sheet sh=wb.getSheet("sheet1");
        for(int j=0; j < 17; j++)
        {
        Row row= sh.getRow(j);
        Cell cell=row.getCell(0);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(1);
        //get the dollar amount from the spread sheet
        driver.findElement(By.name("isc_MXCurrency3_0")).sendKeys("cell");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(2);
        //Pay form the WFS PB CLICKING the drop down
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_90")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(3);
        //Selecting the account number from the drop down
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_PickListMenu_1_body_cell0_1")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(4);
        //Your payment reference ID
        driver.findElement(By.name("isc_MXTextInput_5")).sendKeys("cell");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(5);
        //Clicking on the purpose drop down 
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_A0")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(6);
        //Selecting third option from purpose drop down
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_PickListMenu_1_body_cell0_0")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(7);
        //Clicking on the Standing settlement instruction
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_9Y")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        cell=row.getCell(8);
        //Selecting the SSI on the standing settlement instruction
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_9U")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //System.out.println(cell);
        //Enter the text on the Internal comments text area
        driver.findElement(By.name("isc_MXTextArea_0")).sendKeys("cell");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Clicking on the Enter Button
        driver.findElement(By.id("isc_AB")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        }

    }


    }
```

Below is the error message:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) on port 44745
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"isc_PickListMenu_1_body_cell0_1"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 70 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'DTCD28244FD19AF', ip: '172.25.82.144', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\Users\U524915\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11176_19426}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 8a52a58967ae1d511cc6298c24f4226a
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=isc_PickListMenu_1_body_cell0_1}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:403)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:345)
    at paymenttransfer.PaymentTransfer.main(PaymentTransfer.java:63)
```

Comment: I tried reformatting this code, but it wouldn't let me save my changes because it's just a large amount of code and not enough details. Please add some context if possible :)

Comment: Please indenting first  if you just copy and paste. I think it will runs and stopped after few seconds, Please try now. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what stack overflow requires for a code vs. text ratio when editing, so I'll just leave the formatting alone :)

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a `NoSuchElementException` on this line: `driver.findElement(By.id("isc_PickListMenu_1_body_cell0_1")).click();`

This could be caused by several different problems, I'll mention two here:

1. If this is the line that always fails, it's likely that there is no element with the id `isc_PickListMenu_1_body_cell0_1` when your test gets to that point.
2. If you have random different lines fail, then you probably need to start waiting for the elements to be available before interacting with them.

Here is one approach to that:

```
By elemBy = By.id("isc_PickListMenu_1_body_cell0_1")
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elemBy));
```

Then you'll be ready to find the element and use it:

```
driver.findElement(elemBy).click();
```

From a stability standpoint, this test looks like it might be trying to do too much, which can make it really difficult to figure out what's going wrong. I'd suggest making it do one small specific use case if possible.